# Triple-nested List<> in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, nested-lists

I asked a question not too long ago about multi-dimensional and jagged arrays in C#.  Well, I was trying the List class instead and was running into a bit of a jam.  What happens is only a few of the values in wtflist actually make it to the end of Main().  How can I make sure all of the data gets in (and stays in) wtflist?

Edit:  Here is my **NEW** code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleIometerParser
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int linenum = 0;
        public static int totaldisks = 0;
        public static int disk = 0;

        public static List<List<List<string>>> overallList = new List<List<List<string>>>();

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = args[0];
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filename);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Processing Data...");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] linearray;
                string lineNoQuotes;

                char[] delimiter = new Char[] { ',' };

                lineNoQuotes = line.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                lineNoQuotes = lineNoQuotes.Replace("'", string.Empty);

                linearray = lineNoQuotes.Split(delimiter);
                totaldisks = (linearray.Length - 1) / 10;

                for (disk = 0; disk < totaldisks; disk++)
                {
                    List<List<string>> diskDataList = new List<List<string>>();
                    List<string> dataList = new List<string>();

                    dataList.Add("");
                    dataList.Add(args[1]);
                    dataList.Add(linearray[0]);

                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        int arraypos = disk + (i * totaldisks);
                        dataList.Add(linearray[arraypos].ToString());
                        diskDataList.Add(dataList);
                    }
                    overallList.Add(diskDataList);
                }
                linenum++;
            }

            int count1 = 0;
            int count2 = 0;
            int count3 = 0;

            foreach (var wtf in overallList)
            {
                foreach (var lol in wtf)
                {
                    foreach (var zomg in lol)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("overallList[{0},{1},{2}]: {3}", count1, count2, count3, zomg);
                        count3++;
                    }
                    count3 = 0;
                    count2++;
                }
                count2 = 0;
                count1++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Data Processed Successfully.");
            Console.Read();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

New Output:

```
Processing Data...
overallList[0,0,0]:
overallList[0,0,1]: 1
overallList[0,0,2]: Column1
overallList[0,0,3]: Column4
overallList[0,0,4]: Column7
overallList[0,0,5]: Column10
overallList[0,0,6]: Column13
overallList[0,0,7]: Column16
overallList[0,0,8]: Column19
overallList[0,0,9]: Column22
overallList[0,0,10]: Column25
overallList[0,0,11]: Column28
overallList[0,1,0]:
overallList[0,1,1]: 1
overallList[0,1,2]: Column1
overallList[0,1,3]: Column5
overallList[0,1,4]: Column8
overallList[0,1,5]: Column11
overallList[0,1,6]: Column14
overallList[0,1,7]: Column17
overallList[0,1,8]: Column20
overallList[0,1,9]: Column23
overallList[0,1,10]: Column26
overallList[0,1,11]: Column29
overallList[0,2,0]:
overallList[0,2,1]: 1
overallList[0,2,2]: Column1
overallList[0,2,3]: Column6
overallList[0,2,4]: Column9
overallList[0,2,5]: Column12
overallList[0,2,6]: Column15
overallList[0,2,7]: Column18
overallList[0,2,8]: Column21
overallList[0,2,9]: Column24
overallList[0,2,10]: Column27
overallList[0,2,11]: Column30
overallList[1,0,0]:
overallList[1,0,1]: 1
overallList[1,0,2]: 07/08/10 03:04 PM
overallList[1,0,3]:
overallList[1,0,4]:
overallList[1,0,5]:
overallList[1,0,6]: 0
overallList[1,0,7]:
overallList[1,0,8]:
overallList[1,0,9]:
overallList[1,0,10]:
overallList[1,0,11]:
overallList[1,1,0]:
overallList[1,1,1]: 1
overallList[1,1,2]: 07/08/10 03:04 PM
overallList[1,1,3]:
overallList[1,1,4]:
overallList[1,1,5]: 0
overallList[1,1,6]:
overallList[1,1,7]:
overallList[1,1,8]:
overallList[1,1,9]:
overallList[1,1,10]:
overallList[1,1,11]:
overallList[1,2,0]:
overallList[1,2,1]: 1
overallList[1,2,2]: 07/08/10 03:04 PM
overallList[1,2,3]:
overallList[1,2,4]:
overallList[1,2,5]: 0
overallList[1,2,6]:
overallList[1,2,7]:
overallList[1,2,8]:
overallList[1,2,9]:
overallList[1,2,10]:
overallList[1,2,11]:
overallList[2,0,0]:
overallList[2,0,1]: 1
overallList[2,0,2]: 07/08/10 03:06 PM
overallList[2,0,3]: 98.6
overallList[2,0,4]: 0.02
overallList[2,0,5]: 0.02
overallList[2,0,6]: 0
overallList[2,0,7]: 508500.98
overallList[2,0,8]: 70684.4
overallList[2,0,9]: 10.91
overallList[2,0,10]: 30.66
overallList[2,0,11]: 437816.59
overallList[2,1,0]:
overallList[2,1,1]: 1
overallList[2,1,2]: 07/08/10 03:06 PM
overallList[2,1,3]: 0.02
overallList[2,1,4]: 0.02
overallList[2,1,5]: 0
overallList[2,1,6]: 501532.1
overallList[2,1,7]: 70684.4
overallList[2,1,8]: 10.91
overallList[2,1,9]: 29.84
overallList[2,1,10]: 430847.7
overallList[2,1,11]: 18.93
overallList[2,2,0]:
overallList[2,2,1]: 1
overallList[2,2,2]: 07/08/10 03:06 PM
overallList[2,2,3]: 0
overallList[2,2,4]: 0
overallList[2,2,5]: 0
overallList[2,2,6]: 6968.88
overallList[2,2,7]: 0
overallList[2,2,8]: 0
overallList[2,2,9]: 0.81
overallList[2,2,10]: 6968.88
overallList[2,2,11]: 0.81
overallList[3,0,0]:
overallList[3,0,1]: 1
overallList[3,0,2]: 07/08/10 03:07 PM
overallList[3,0,3]: 99.86
overallList[3,0,4]: 0
overallList[3,0,5]: 0
overallList[3,0,6]: 0
overallList[3,0,7]: 84469.57
overallList[3,0,8]: 273.07
overallList[3,0,9]: 0.07
overallList[3,0,10]: 6.14
overallList[3,0,11]: 84196.5
overallList[3,1,0]:
overallList[3,1,1]: 1
overallList[3,1,2]: 07/08/10 03:07 PM
overallList[3,1,3]: 0
overallList[3,1,4]: 0
overallList[3,1,5]: 0
overallList[3,1,6]: 78092.25
overallList[3,1,7]: 273.07
overallList[3,1,8]: 0.07
overallList[3,1,9]: 5.39
overallList[3,1,10]: 77819.18
overallList[3,1,11]: 5.32
overallList[3,2,0]:
overallList[3,2,1]: 1
overallList[3,2,2]: 07/08/10 03:07 PM
overallList[3,2,3]: 0
overallList[3,2,4]: 0
overallList[3,2,5]: 0
overallList[3,2,6]: 6377.32
overallList[3,2,7]: 0
overallList[3,2,8]: 0
overallList[3,2,9]: 0.76
overallList[3,2,10]: 6377.32
overallList[3,2,11]: 0.76
overallList[4,0,0]:
overallList[4,0,1]: 1
overallList[4,0,2]: 07/08/10 03:09 PM
overallList[4,0,3]: 99.83
overallList[4,0,4]: 0
overallList[4,0,5]: 0
overallList[4,0,6]: 0
overallList[4,0,7]: 35277.63
overallList[4,0,8]: 1849.23
overallList[4,0,9]: 0.32
overallList[4,0,10]: 5.1
overallList[4,0,11]: 33428.4
overallList[4,1,0]:
overallList[4,1,1]: 1
overallList[4,1,2]: 07/08/10 03:09 PM
overallList[4,1,3]: 0
overallList[4,1,4]: 0
overallList[4,1,5]: 0
overallList[4,1,6]: 25764.05
overallList[4,1,7]: 1576.11
overallList[4,1,8]: 0.29
overallList[4,1,9]: 4.05
overallList[4,1,10]: 24187.94
overallList[4,1,11]: 3.76
overallList[4,2,0]:
overallList[4,2,1]: 1
overallList[4,2,2]: 07/08/10 03:09 PM
overallList[4,2,3]: 0
overallList[4,2,4]: 0
overallList[4,2,5]: 0
overallList[4,2,6]: 9513.58
overallList[4,2,7]: 273.12
overallList[4,2,8]: 0.03
overallList[4,2,9]: 1.06
overallList[4,2,10]: 9240.46
overallList[4,2,11]: 1.02
overallList[5,0,0]:
overallList[5,0,1]: 1
overallList[5,0,2]: 07/08/10 03:10 PM
overallList[5,0,3]: 99.91
overallList[5,0,4]: 0
overallList[5,0,5]: 0
overallList[5,0,6]: 0
overallList[5,0,7]: 34662.41
overallList[5,0,8]: 182.04
overallList[5,0,9]: 0.03
overallList[5,0,10]: 4.92
overallList[5,0,11]: 34480.36
overallList[5,1,0]:
overallList[5,1,1]: 1
overallList[5,1,2]: 07/08/10 03:10 PM
overallList[5,1,3]: 0
overallList[5,1,4]: 0
overallList[5,1,5]: 0
overallList[5,1,6]: 25691.03
overallList[5,1,7]: 91.02
overallList[5,1,8]: 0.02
overallList[5,1,9]: 4.06
overallList[5,1,10]: 25600.01
overallList[5,1,11]: 4.03
overallList[5,2,0]:
overallList[5,2,1]: 1
overallList[5,2,2]: 07/08/10 03:10 PM
overallList[5,2,3]: 4.67E-005
overallList[5,2,4]: 0
overallList[5,2,5]: 0
overallList[5,2,6]: 8971.38
overallList[5,2,7]: 91.02
overallList[5,2,8]: 0.01
overallList[5,2,9]: 0.87
overallList[5,2,10]: 8880.36
overallList[5,2,11]: 0.86
Data Processed Successfully.
```

Here's the **OLD** code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleIometerParser
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int linenum = 0;
        public static int totaldisks = 0;
        public static int disk = 0;

        public static List<List<List<string>>> wtflist = new List<List<List<string>>>();

        //public static string[,,] sqlarray;

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = args[0];
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filename);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Processing Data...");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Linenum: " + linenum);
                string[] linearray;
                string lineNoQuotes;

                char[] delimiter = new Char[] { ',' };

                lineNoQuotes = line.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                lineNoQuotes = lineNoQuotes.Replace("'", string.Empty);

                linearray = lineNoQuotes.Split(delimiter);
                totaldisks = (linearray.Length - 1) / 10;

                //sqlarray = new string[totaldisks, lines.Length, 13];

                for (disk = 0; disk < totaldisks; disk++)
                {
                    List<List<string>> lollist = new List<List<string>>();

                    //sqlarray[disk, linenum, 0] = ""; //blank field for the SQL id field
                    //sqlarray[disk, linenum, 1] = args[1]; //testid
                    //sqlarray[disk, linenum, 2] = linearray[0]; //time

                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        List<string> zomglist = new List<string>();

                        int arraypos = disk + (i * totaldisks);
                        //sqlarray[disk, linenum, i + 2] = linearray[arraypos].ToString();
                        //Console.WriteLine("sqlarray[{0},{1},{2}]: {3}", disk, linenum, i, sqlarray[disk, linenum, i]);
                        zomglist.Add(linearray[arraypos].ToString());

                        Console.WriteLine("zomglist data: {0}", zomglist.Last());

                        if (i == 9) lollist.Add(zomglist);
                    }
                    wtflist.Add(lollist);
                }
                linenum++;
            }

            foreach (var wtf in wtflist)
            {
                foreach (var lol in wtf)
                {
                    foreach (var zomg in lol)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ZOMG: " + zomg);
                    }
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Data Processed Successfully.");
            Console.Read();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What happens is only a few of the values in wtflist actually make it to the end of Main().  One would usually like all of them to make it to the end :)

Comment: Ok... still don't understand.  What is an example of one of the items from wtflist that made it to the end?

Comment: My question is: List<List<List<string>>>?  Really?

Comment: Well let me add an index value to the console.writeline.

Comment: Yes, really.  I was using jagged arrays, but that was another can of worms.

Comment: You're assuming that your triple-nested list is being populated correctly. It's probably not. Your code is a mess. Try and clean it up and make sure you're getting the right data in.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I like how you name your variables.

Comment: Well, by "really" I mean, surely there is a cleaner way of doing this with a set of objects.  Technically, it will work.  Maintenance, on the other hand, will be difficult (especially if its somebody else has to read and understand this code).  I think if you did that, the answer (good find, @md5sum) will be more likely to jump out at you.

Comment: Yes.  It's a CSV parser obviously, and if you want to see the PHP side of it, here's a link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720939/why-is-this-multi-dimensional-array-acting-funny-in-c  
  
That gentleman pointed me to using lists.

Comment: I don't know the application (i.e. context), but I find "totaldisks = (linearray.Length - 1) / 10;" a little suspect.  Where is that 10 coming from?

Comment: There are always 10 fields per disk :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line: `if (i == 9) lollist.Add(zomglist);` means that only 1/10th (or every 10th) of the `zomglist`s created will get added to the `lollist`. Looks like it's executing perfectly to me.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new zomglist every time through the for i loop, but only adding it to lollist when i == 9.  The other 9 zomglists are lost.

But it seems that the purpose of the for i loop is to fill the zomglist, so you really need to move the create of zomglist & it addition to lollist to outside the loop:

```
List<string> zomglist = new List<string>(); 
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
{ 
      int arraypos = disk + (i * totaldisks); 
      zomglist.Add(linearray[arraypos].ToString()); 
      Console.WriteLine("zomglist data: {0}", zomglist.Last()); 
}
lollist.Add(zomglist);
```

Similarly, the creation of lollist & it's addition to wtflist needs to be moved outside the for disk loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
                { 
                    List<string> zomglist = new List<string>();
```

which will create a new `zomglist` every time through the loop. I think you want to have a single `zomglist` that you always operate on, like this:

```
                List<string> zomglist = new List<string>(); 
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
                {
```